# Verify that the Bundle identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, xcode13

I want to test the iOS version of my flutter application. I am using `XCode 13.1` and Monterey MacOS which is installed on Virtualbox. I am getting this error message `"Verify that the Bundle identifier in your project is your signing id"`. I don't have a physical device now and I have a free apple ID, not paid development ID.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: No, you have to enroll apple development to create certificate. That certificate helps you to run your application in your device.

Comment: @DishantRajput I don't want to publish it in app store now, is it mandatory to have dev ID?

Comment: Yes, you can .. Add your apple id account first in Xcode preferences and then give permission to your device from Device management.

Comment: @DishantRajput I don't have a physical device, how can I add an emulator

Comment: Then you don't need any apple developer programme to run in emulator or simulator.

Comment: So can I have the ipa file without getting this error message? How? Can you send a complete answer so I can check it as an accepted answer, cause I found a similar question that is not answered yet. @DishantRajput

Comment: oh! for ipa you have to Enroll Apple developer program.